Can human based products be used successfully in making foodstuffs without any resulting products being flops or outing them as human based?
Before I get to the question, I will give a bit of context. Basically I have this organization of cannibals called CCC(Chew, Convert, Continue) that want to of course not only eat people but make others eat people and/or add new members to their ranks. They do this by making human flesh/secretion based or laden products and giving them to the general population in hopes of getting them to join. Food items includes but is not limited to: human flesh stew, human bone broth, human flesh and bones gelatin desserts(Jello, gummy bears & worms, and marshmallows), human flesh hotdogs and sausages, human blood black pudding, human blood candy bars, human flesh sashimi, human milk icecream(or icemilk?) and last but not least human eggs(or blood) and milk based cakes. Heck, they probably even whiten the sugar by passing it through human bone char.
So the question: Can human based products be used successfully in making foodstuffs without any resulting products being flops or outing them as human based?
I should note that this is not a cooking skill based question nor an opinion/taste(no pun intended) question, but rather a question of if human based products can be properly used for culinary purposes in general. While you might like pineapples in jello, but regardless of options, it will not set with them in it. Also, to clear confusion, they are in a modern setting in our world.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Conan. You're still asking two questions here! Question 1 is "can this happen in our world" and question 2 is "can this happen in some other world". Choose one or the other. Make sure whichever you choose does not invalidate any of the answers you've got.

Edited, I just choose our world. IDK if is enough for a reopen, but please VTO if you have not. Folks seem to like this question, so hopefully I will get some good and/or interesting answers.@elemtilas

Frame Challenge
We could talk about regulatory compliance which would be a minefield in-of-itself - but the key issue is one of SUPPLY
In order to have good quality produce, you need good healthy sources.
Let us consider the humble and delicious Cow:
Natural lifespan is 20-30 years. For Beef (on average) they are slaughtered at 18 months old. To put this in perspective, a Cow goes through the equivalent of Puberty at approximately 12 months.
This means that for an equivalent Human, you would need to be slaughtering them at around 18-20 years. They would need to have reasonable muscle and a good layer of fat (fat is flavour...) they would also need to be Drug and Disease free (too much risk of contamination).
This means that the following groups:

The Elderly dying of natural causes
People with terminal illnesses
Drug addicts
The Homeless
Other people who are vulnerable

Are all out of the question as a source for your products.
Now, even if we assume that there is steady supply of Bernd-Jürgen Armando Brandes types - To make any product of any sufficient quantity to achieve any market penetration (hehe penetration) - you will need to kill a boat load of people... Literally.
In NZ (for example) we are slaughtering approximately 13,000 Cows... PER DAY
And bearing in mind a Cow has a lot more meat on it than a Human - we would need to be having the equivalent of the Somme every day.
Needless to say, that sort of death toll is going to raise some eyebrows. Especially amongst young, fit Men.
So unless your product is something that can be used in teeny tiny quantities - before you get to the point where you can worry about regulators, you need to find a way to kill a whole lot of people without anyone noticing - and you can't rely on the sort of people that one would usually target.

If the products are successful then the greatest threat to the CCC's secrecy is probably from their competition. Other food corporations will be buying and testing their food to find out what makes it successful. They will quickly work out that something dodgy is going on when they can't identify the species that the animal products have come from, no one would think to test for human to start with.
There is no surefire way to make a product successful, everyone in market has tried to come up with something that works for everyone since there was first a market and it's not worked yet.

Oh they will identify it, testing for human DNA is common as a check for comtamination of the sample.

@John Huh, I knew they routinely checked DNA on meat products to make sure they were actually [insert meat animal here], especially things like venison and tuna, I didn't know they included human in the search field, even more glad I don't eat the stuff.

its a check for contamination of the sample not the meat, as in did the person screw up collecting it. But when every sample from X comes back positive...

@Ash They check so that you DON'T get meat with people DNA in it.  More disturbing would be if they did not check for it.

@Nosajimiki The fact that they need to check for it to guarantee it isn't happening is more disturbing because of what that says about food industry practices in general.

This problem applies to all food, not just meat.  Someone is just as likely to nick themselves and bleed into your salad as they are into your burger meat... but at least the meat gets cooked.

It is happening, that's why they check for it. Helps track down factories associated with organized crime, as it's long been a favored means of body dumping for them.

@Therac I didn't realise how glad this question would make me to be a vegetarian.

By and large, humans are not top cuisine.
Unless you keep your humans in near-pristine, free-range conditions, feed them a specific healthy diet and control for disease at all times, your human's meat is going to taste like the the worst roadkill-hog pork you found by the side of a country road. "Natural" humans are extreme omnivores, and their meat soaks in all the toxins, bacteria, and contaminants from the entire food-chain below them. Acquired taste does not begin to cover it.
Human milk... well unless you are a baby,(or Homelander), its not going to be your cup of...milk. Human breastmilk does not taste like cow milk at all, its taste is closer to what you would get if you blended whey, butter, goat milk and Parmesan powder. Pretty yucky, and not something you would want in your cereal/coffee.
Eggs - out of the question.
Organs? Possibly. Kidneys and livers are right out due to the amount of soaked-in toxins, but you could probably find some use for a pancreas or spleen.
Blood for blood sausage could work ok-ish.
Amusingly, probably the most efficient, cheapest, and least cruel way to get food out of humans is...semen. Herring semen soup (white Milt soup) is a staple of many Atlantic cuisines. Its supposedly very umami,  I'll go on a limb and assume that you can squeeze more semen out of a human male than out of a herring, and it would be cruelty-free! (unless your livestock is into cruelty I guess, I don't kinkshame).
Moreover, unlike herring, human males can be fed variety of different foodstuffs to change the flavor of their milt (like pineapple for a milder flavor, or cheese for a stronger umami kick).
The thing is, as long as you keep it within all the sanitary-epid rules, (pasteurize the milt, thoroughly test the "livestock") it would be entirely legal. You could probably repurpose goat-milking devices for this purpose, or hire professionals to milk your livestock by hand, for a more "artisan" product.

Human milk is very diverse in flavor because it is flavored by what the mother eats.  Most cow milk tastes the same because all cows eat about the same stuff and they blend the milk of many cows.  The human milk market could easily have a strong niche because there are so many flavors to sample.  One could easily invent 100s of new "Artesian" cheeses based on breast milk and each could sell for top dollar specifically because they appeal to people looking for something different or exclusive.

Maggots can be used to recycle almost any form of protein. They seem to break down anything they eat into very basic constituents before turning them into maggot, so you can feed them with all kinds of unwholesome stuff and end up with a pure foodstuff. If you have surplus humans, then they would turn it into something you could safely eat, if you don't mind rice that moves...
Whether it is actually, traceably human once it has been a maggot is hard to tell. I don't know whether the CCC could use this.
See also Michael Palin and Terry Jones 'Secrets' chocolate.

They test animal feed as well, to prevent closed parasite cycles. so this is slightly more likely but not much more. –
John


Can human based products be used successfully in making foodstuffs without any resulting products being flops or outing them as human based?

No, not for long. Testing would out them as human content if the flesh isn't processed enough, and while this would be ok in some places, in others it would be taken pretty seriously.
We already consume human based products, but not in a recognisable form. So chances are it's in the bread you eat, but you just don't know it and since it's FDA approved, it's not illegal at all.

We already consume human based products: care to give some examples?

What is in bread that you think comes directly from a human?

I didn't give you any downvote. But such answers tend to get downvoted.

@Ash L-Cysteine is widely used in dough in big bread/ baked goods producers, one of the main sources of this is human hair. Not in Europe though, where it's not allowed (I think). You guys shouldn't downvote just because you don't know common things. I just answer questions, don't want to be a primary school teacher

The primary industrial source of L-Cysteine, worldwide, is poultry feathers, the alternative is hog hair, nowhere is human hair used as a source material for consumer goods, at least not anywhere in the modern world. As far as I can tell it's not even added to bread, it's original to the wheat flour.

@Ash you're wrong. Try looking it up. I just googled it, plenty of evidence... but as I said, I'm not interested in being a basic level teacher

I did look it up and I quote "...to spite persistent rumours human hair is almost never used as source material....".

It's not worth downvoting you. You're inability to do basic research is frustrating though.

Seems to be some sort of glitch... my comment keeps disappearing... @Ash Don't get frustrated, it's not worth it. I'd rather have the downvote than ruin someones peace of mind.

downvoted for making a rather bold claim with no supporting evidence, which makes the answer worthless.

How does telling someone they're eating people, without any supporting evidence mind you, not ruin their peace of mind?

@Kilisi --- Looked it up. It's synthesised from animal products like feathers and hair. Why go the tip behind a barber shop to collect hair when you've got industrial chicken processing plants?
